# Data transpose in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have the following table:

```
  type          sw_rel          id         oper_name          test_name
test on a        1.0           1478       first_stage      initial stage
test on b        1.0           1478       first_stage      initial stage
test on c        1.0           1478       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 1       2.0           1510       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 1       2.0           1511       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 1       2.0           1512       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 2       2.0           1513       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 2       2.0           1514       first_stage      initial stage
at stage 2       2.0           1515       first_stage      initial stage
```

I am trying to get the below output. but couldn't get.

```
test on a,1.0,first_stage,initial stage,1478
test on b,1.0,first_stage,initial stage,1478
test on c,1.0,first_stage,initial stage,1478
at stage 1,2.0,first_stage,initial stage,1510,1511,1512
at stage 2,2.0,first_stage,initial stage,1513,1514,1515
```

Here, I am trying to write an Oracle SQL transpose query.

**main logic is**
rows having same `(type,sw_rel,oper_name,test_name)` should have `id` row wise (comma separated).

Answer (score 0):

I think yo can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select type, sw_rel, oper_name, test_name,
       list_agg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids
from table t
group by type, sw_rel, oper_name, test_name;
```